# How to split Math work into worker threads Java

Tags: java, multithreading, math, synchronized

I'm developing a Java app that calcuates numbers to powers. I would like to take advantage of my quad core computer, as only one core is being used with this application. I've looked at different tutorials on how to syncronize threads, but I don't really get it. My code is below:

```
public class Bignum{

public static void main(String[] args){

    Random generator = new Random();   
    long start = System.nanoTime();   
    Random generator1 = new Random();

for (long i=0; i<9000;i++){

    int power = generator1.nextInt (17) + 2;
    int power1 = generator1.nextInt (25) + 2;
    int power2 = generator1.nextInt (72) + 2;

    BigInteger num = BigInteger.valueOf (generator.nextInt (7895) + 1);
    BigInteger num1 = BigInteger.valueOf (generator.nextInt (1250) + 1);
    BigInteger num2 = BigInteger.valueOf (generator.nextInt (9765) + 1);

    BigInteger add = num.pow(power);
    BigInteger add1 = num1.pow(power1);
    BigInteger add2 = num2.pow(power2);

    BigInteger sum = add.add(add1);

}

}
}
```

So, for example, how could I have one thread do this:

```
    int power = generator1.nextInt (17) + 2;
    int power1 = generator1.nextInt (25) + 2;
    int power2 = generator1.nextInt (72) + 2;
```

Another do this:

```
    BigInteger num = BigInteger.valueOf (generator.nextInt (7895) + 1);
    BigInteger num1 = BigInteger.valueOf (generator.nextInt (1250) + 1);
    BigInteger num2 = BigInteger.valueOf (generator.nextInt (9765) + 1);
```

Another this:

```
    BigInteger add = num.pow(power);
    BigInteger add1 = num1.pow(power1);
    BigInteger add2 = num2.pow(power2);
```

And the last one do this:

```
    BigInteger sum = add.add(add1);
```

How could I do that? Also, how could I still repeat that 9000 times? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think it would be best to run each of the three in a different thread rather then each step. then you sync until all are done and add

Comment: Well you wouldn't basically the operations are too small. Setting up the thread would take much longer than it would be alive. Three threads doing 3000 iterations each would make sense though.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Could you show me how I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i really recommend [this book](http://books.google.com/books/about/Java_Concurrency_in_Practice.html?id=EK43StEVfJIC) to get started with java multi-threading.  It's like the bible of this stuff.

That being said, you're going to need a thread pool to hold your tasks, and youre going to need to make a 'worker' class (which will become the thread) that handles what it needs to do, and properly exits/returns its value.

-Make your thread pool

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_NUMBER_THREADS_AT_ONCE);
```

-Make your worker task

```
public static class WorkerTask implements Runnable {
    //member vars if you need em

    WorkerTask() {
        //initialize member vars if you need to
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
            //do your work here 
    }
}
```

-Add tasks to the thread pool like this:

```
for( each task you need ){
        Runnable worker = new WorkerTask( constructor params );
        executor.execute(worker);
    }
```

Finally, this leaves two questions:

How do I wait for them to finish?

How do I return a value from a thread?

The fact is that both of these questions have a bunch of ways to solve which might be specific to your problem, but I think in this case you can do something simple.  I recommend a global static **class** variable which will have global scope and be able to be accessed by all threads.  Be careful here, dont edit the same values as other threads, so use something like a ConcurrentHashMap, and when a thread has its answer, just add the thread id and its answer to the hashmap.  ex:  concurrentMap.add(threadId, value);

To wait until all the tasks are done I usually do something like this:

```
executor.shutdown();  //signal that you want to shutdown executor
while(!executor.isTerminated()){
        Thread.sleep(10000);  //wait ten seconds
        System.out.println("Waiting 10 seconds");
}
// now finally traverse your value map and output your answers
```

Comment: The only problem with this answer is your use of the name `WorkerThread`.  These are NOT threads.  They are *tasks*.  Using a name that implies that they are threads is liable to confuse readers.

Comment: yes, i probably should have explained the difference.  These are runnable tasks that the thread pool will spin up into threads once it decides it is 'their turn to run.'
Ill edit my answer for future readers.

Comment: The way you shut down your executor is not recommended... you could wait 10 seconds for no good reason. You can use awaitTermination to do the same with no redundant wait. Also need to handle the case where tasks did not finish. Look here for sample: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Comment: I realize that this is the 'better' way to do it, but awaitTermination locks the main thread, and requires a timeout period.  Adding monitoring such as a progress bar or updates to the console requires a whole other thread, while in a simple program such as this, looping on a while doesn't seem so bad.

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8 parallel maths can be quite elegant. Code below takes advantage of the fact that "+" operation is additive, so values can be summed in any order.

So the code below create a sequence of numbers in parallel and reduces (sums) them in a single thread.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import static java.math.BigInteger.valueOf;
import static java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current;

public class Bignum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Optional<BigInteger> sum = IntStream.range(0, 9000)
            .parallel()       <-- this enables parallel execution
            .mapToObj(value -> {
                ThreadLocalRandom generator = current();

                int power = generator.nextInt(17) + 2;
                int power1 = generator.nextInt(25) + 2;
                int power2 = generator.nextInt(72) + 2;

                BigInteger num = valueOf(generator.nextInt(7895) + 1);
                BigInteger num1 = valueOf(generator.nextInt(1250) + 1);
                BigInteger num2 = valueOf(generator.nextInt(9765) + 1);

                BigInteger add = num.pow(power);
                BigInteger add1 = num1.pow(power1);
                BigInteger add2 = num2.pow(power2);

                return add.add(add1).add(add2);
            })
            .reduce(BigInteger::add);

        System.out.println(sum.get());
    }
}
```

Comment: Add is indeed "additive", but I think what you meant was commutative :)

Comment: Not willing being too much anal about this, `reduce` requires associativity and `+` is a binary operation in an [Additive Group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_group). :-)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer working with queues for thread input and output, just see the example in the docs: http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

In general there are 2.5 reasons for using threads to begin with:

1. In multi cpu systems
2. when dealing with IO (monitor, mouse, keyboard, sockets, read / write files etc.)
3. for timers

Assuming you are not doing IO and not need timers, having more threads than your system CPU is going to slow you dowwwwwwwwwwwn

Comment: What about GUIs?   ;)

Comment: You could classify it as that. not all guis require input, so it seemed a bit broad to people who dont understand why